# My basic cipher based encryption method in C++ is not working properly, how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, string, encryption

```
void encrypt(char *string){
    int i, shift;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        shift = 12+i;
        while(((int)string[i]+shift) > 122){
            shift-=26;
        }
        string[i]+=shift;
    }
    for(i = 4; i < 6; i++){
        shift = 12+i;
        while(((int)string[i]+shift) > 90){
            shift-=26;
        }
        string[i]+=shift;
    }
    for(i = 6; i < 8; i++){
       shift = 12+i;
        while(((int)string[i]+shift) > 57){
            shift-=10;
        }
        string[i]+=shift;
    }
    for(i = 8; i < 10; i++){
        shift = 12+i;

        if((((int)string[i])>=33)&&(((int)string[i])<=47)){
            while(((int)string[i]+shift) > 47){
                shift-=15;
            }
        }
        else{
            while(((int)string[i]+shift) > 64){
                shift-=7;
            }
        }
        string[i]+=shift;
    }
}
```

I made this function to encrypt a string which will be of 10 characters and the first 4 of them are going to be lowercase letters, next 2 will be uppercase letters, next 2, some numbers and the last 2 will be some special characters. So supposedly, it shifts every character in its range (and wraps the encrypted replacement back to the beginning of the range if it falls out of it) depending upon on which place the character is in the string. The shift is equal to 12+[the index of the character in the string]. (To know why I did all that in the last loop you can see in any [ascii chart](http://www.asciichart.com/) that there two different groups of special characters).

The problem, now, is that the function is shifting every character in its range except for the first one. (okay, I didn't check if it gave the correct replacement. I just saw that the replacement was from the same range (like lowercase letter for lowercase letter and number for number) and assumed it's working properly for them :P) The first one's replacement is some weird unrecognized character. I used the Borland compiler. Is it the compiler? Is it the code?

Comment: 1) _Please help asap._ SO is **not** an emergency hotline. 2) What did you attempt to resolve the issue on your own? For example, did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out where the code does something, that deviates from your expectations?

Comment: BTW, if you are in a hurry, use a *debugger*.  Using a debugger is faster than posting to Stackoverflow and *waiting* for somebody to use a debugger on your code.

Comment: Hint:  modulo arithmetic.  Look it up.

Comment: I would recommend replacing most of those constants with the corresponding characters. For example, `'z'` has the value `122`. It's clear the value `122` is meant to represent `z` in this context. No need for all of these magic numbers.

Comment: Look up Caesar Cipher.  While you are researching, also look at  ROT13 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest placing all your valid characters into a string, then using the `%` operator.

```
const std::string valid_characters = 
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*";
const unsigned int shift_offset = 13;

std::string::size_type position = valid_characters.find(incoming_character);
position = (position + shift_offset) % valid_characters.length();
char result = valid_characters[position];
```

You will have to check the `position` value because `find` will return `std::string::npos` if the character does not exist in the `valid_characters` string.